# Regex for Address working in Regex 101 (Python) not in Python using re.match?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, jupyter, regex-group

I have the following Python script (in Jupyter) which is supposed to extract address information using regex (unit numbers are already cleaned up and street types are abbreviated before this step):

```
type_opts = r"Terrace|Way|Walk|St|Rd|Ave|Cl|Ct|Cres|Blvd|Dr|Ln|Pl|Sq|Pde"
road_attrs_pattern = r"(?P<rd_no>\w?\d+(\-\d+)?\w?\s+)(?P<rd_nm>[a-zA-z \-]+)(?#\s+(?P<rd_tp>" + type_opts + ")"
print("Road Attr Pattern: ", road_attrs_pattern)
road_attrs = re.match(road_attrs_pattern, proc_addr)
road_num = road_attrs.group('rd_no').strip()
print("Road number: ", road_num)
road_name = road_attrs.group('rd_nm').strip()
print("Road name: ", road_name)
road_type = road_attrs.group('rd_tp').strip()
print("Road type: ", road_type)
```

I'm using this address:

```
Burrah lodge, 15 Anne Jameson Pl
```

This results in the following print-out:

```
Road Attr Pattern:  (?P<rd_no>\w?\d+(\-\d+)?\w?\s+)(?P<rd_nm>[a-zA-z \-]+)(?#\s+(?P<rd_tp>Terrace|Way|Walk|St|Rd|Ave|Cl|Ct|Cres|Blvd|Dr|Ln|Pl|Sq|Pde)
```

But then throws an error saying the street number is not available `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'`.

However a copy-paste in Regex101 [here](https://regex101.com/r/hhf3dw/1) says it should work, and looking over the Regex it's my view that it should work also...

It should print-out the following:

```
Road Attr Pattern:  (?P<rd_no>\w?\d+(\-\d+)?\w?\s+)(?P<rd_nm>[a-zA-z \-]+)(?#\s+(?P<rd_tp>Terrace|Way|Walk|St|Rd|Ave|Cl|Ct|Cres|Blvd|Dr|Ln|Pl|Sq|Pde)
Road number: 15
Road name: Anne Jameson
Road type: Pl
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html), `re.match` checks for a match *at the beginning of the string*.

Since you're looking for a match that starts partway through the string, you'll want `re.search` instead.

Comment: OK, that's embarrassing, thanks for your help. I'll adjust the question as well to help other people point to it...